# Detect that mmap-ed file has been truncated

Tags: c++, mmap

I have a file `mmap(2)`-ed in a C++ library and I have a function which reads from that file by accessing the `mmap`ped memory.

I would like to handle the situation gracefully where somebody else truncates the file while I have it open.

The problem is that access to `mmap`ed memory rises `SIGBUS` when the file is truncated.
I can install a signal handler, but the only way I could see to get out of it is to use `setjmp`/`longjmp` and that breaks all C++ things like exceptions and automatic variables.

Is there

- a (preferably cheap) way to **detect that the underlying file has been truncated before reading the memory**?
- A **C++ way to escape from the `SIGBUS` signal handler** that does not screw up the rest of the program?

Comment: You should lock the file, e.g. flock(), so someone else can't mess with it while it's memmapped.

Comment: Allegedly GCC has `-fnon-call-exceptions` which turns signals like SIGSEGV or SIGBUS into C++ exceptions. But it isn't supported on all platforms (for example it does nothing under Windows), and avoiding the truncation in the first place using `flock` is probably much more elegant, too.